# detect eye iris in a binary image

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing, emgucv

I am developing an eye tracker application in emgu CV, To track eyes i need to detect iris accurately ,So i used hough circles , but in some cases it fails because the shape of iris is not a perfect circle, So i decided to convert eye image in to binary and detect iris ,

To convert it to binary i used

> grayframeright_1 = grayframeright_1.ThresholdBinary(new
>   Gray(threshold_value), new Gray(220));

and the result is

[image]

Now how can i detect iris in the above binary image ?Can i run blob detector to detect iris ?

Please help me to figure this out, your help will be highly appreciated , I am running out of time for my deadline.

Providing code sample would be useful

Thanks in advance

Comment: What does this have to do with C#? What have you tried?

Comment: Actually, it doesn't have to do with any programming language despite the fact maybe he's coding it in C#.

Comment: I have tried blob detection but it is detecting whole image as blob...

I am implementing this application in emgu CV.

Answer (score 0):

You can try [erosion](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fmyE7DiaIYQ). I've used it in a image processing class at university to find the visual center of airplanes in the sky and it worked surprisingly well.

Erosion is a fairly [simple operator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erosion_%28morphology%29) used in broader practice like *blob detection*, which you already mentioned.

Erode should remove border pixels of irregular shapes, leaving at last, just a moment before the shape completely vanishes, only few pixels. The geometrical center of those pixels is *c*, the visual center of the irregular shape. Starting from *c* draw a circle of radius *r* which is completely *inscribed* in the irregular shape. The circle at *c* with radius *r* is an approximation of the iris. Or at least so the story goes.

When I say erosion I mean this: [example of erosion](https://www.cs.auckland.ac.nz/courses/compsci773s1c/lectures/ImageProcessing-html/topic4.htm#erosion)

> This was just my personal idea based on university work, I've never done this in the industry.

Maybe you should look at a more serious approach to the problem which does not use erosion but wavelets: [Iris recognition](http://www.cl.cam.ac.uk/~jgd1000/irisrecog.pdf)

I'm very curious. If you try this could you please share your results/findings? A quick comment would suffice!

Comment: Thank you for answering the question , I have tried erode operation in emgu cv ,It increases the thickness of the image or give a blurred image, 
but how can it be used to detect a shape of iris ?
please correct me if i am wrong